# openssl configuration issue which lets only root user correctly verify web server certificates

Tags: permissions, root, openssl

when I check the SSL certificate chain of a web server on my raspbian system, e.g. by running

```
openssl s_client -connect plumbr.eu:443
```

I get the following error output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
...
```

However, when I `sudo` the very same, then everything works fine:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.plumbr.eu
verify return:1
...
```

The same goes for several other web sites I tested. I'm pretty sure that this is not the expected behaviour. Does someone know how to fix this, or at least a hint where to look? The search for existing solutions was unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer by [some guy on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160354/openssl-configuration-issue-which-lets-only-root-user-correctly-verify-web-serve) and I repost it here for reference, if somebody ever stumbles upon the same issue...

The problem was the file/directory permissions of

```
/etc/ssl/certs/
```

which was accessible by root only -- I had to

```
chmod o+rx
```

as well. The actual certificate directory

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates
```

had the permissions set correctly, though -.-